# Magento quick search by SKU

Tags: magento

When I try to search products by SKU, I get incomplete results. For example: I have products with SKU `IR-CP-CH_1` and `A-453-B-I_1`. Both products are configurable products, both are visible for Catalog, Search. I get correct result for query `IR-CP-CH_1` and no result for `A-453-B-I_1`.

Indexes are rebuilt. I use combined search type (like + fulltext). In advanced search everything works fine.

Comment: Are those SKUs visible on the currently selected site?

Comment: The missing product checklist: is visibile, is associated to the store / store view, is associated to (some) categories, has stock and price.

Comment: Yes, they are visible in catalog.

Comment: Visibility - yes; is associated to the store / store view - i have only one store and only one store view; is associated to (some) categories - yes; has stock and price - yes

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a quick look in your database at the table `catalogsearch_fulltext`. In the `data_index` column you should be able to see the SKUs as part of the full text string Magento creates for quick searching in.

See if you can either manually spot the elusive SKU 'A-453-B-I_1' or hit it with an

```
SELECT * FROM catalogsearch_fulltext WHERE data_index LIKE '%453%'
```

Maybe the SKU got entered with some strange characters or a space instead of a hyphen. You could search in the `product_id` column instead to see what search string Magento does have for that SKU.

If the string *is* in the table and the character glyphs match exactly, then I think you are looking to indexing, caching, stock, store views etc as suggested in the comments above by others

If the string is not in the table at all then I think you are looking to 'visibility'.

If you look in the table `catalogsearch_query` and find your search string 'A-453-B-I_1' then look to the `num_results` column - if that value is greater than zero then items were found but it's not displaying that product for some reason.

**EDIT following comments below

Actually I think you should remove that '0' result from the `catalogsearch_query` table. You could remove it using SQL or phpmyadmin. Magento will return a result from `catalogsearch_query` if it finds one rather that search `catalogsearch_fulltext` every time.

It is possible that at some point the result was '0' but now it is non-zero but Magento is stuck with the '0 results' in the `catalogsearch_query` table.

There is more analysis that can be done, but try that first and if it still isn't right we can look at trapping the database query to try to understand why Magento thinks the result is zero.

Comment: Ok, string 'A-453-B-I_1' is in the table `catalogsearch_fulltext` in `data_index`.  In `catalogsearch_query` for this query - 0 results.

Comment: I have only one store view. it's id is 1. All products are assigned to this store view

Comment: All products are assigned to this store view. Cache is disabled. product is in the stock. It is configurable. His children is in stock. Qty of children - 999. Configurable product (A-453-B-I_1) visibility - catalog, search. His children - search. Inexes was rebuilded.

Answer (score 0):

For information, in my case, a free module (activo_catalogsearch) was breaking the research by sku because it was not up to date and probably conflicting with magento 1.9.4.1 (worked fine before with magento 1.9.2.1)